# Update database based on form input

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server, forms

I am trying to perform an update on a database based on the input of a form but facing an issue. I have tried the below but it is not executing the command on the database. It needs to read in a value for decision and carry out a query based on the decision.Can anyone spot the issue here ?

html form code :

```
<center><div class="container">
<form action="update.php" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you  wish to update ?');">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="decision">Would you like to add or subtract from current quantity?</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-75">
    <select id="decision" name="decision">
      <option value="add">Add</option>
      <option value="subtract">Subtract</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="License Group ID">License Group ID</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-75">
    <input type="number" name="LicenseGroupID" placeholder="LicenseGroupID">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="Quantity">Quantity</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-75">
    <input type="number" name="Quantity" placeholder="Quantity">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <input type="submit" value="Update">
</div>
```

update.php

```
<html>
 <?php 
$serverName = "tcp:xxx,1433";
$options = array(  "UID" => "aalicensemanager",  "PWD" => "xxx",   "Database" => "AALicenseManager");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $options);

if( $conn === false )
 {
 echo "Could not connect.\n";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }  
$decision = $_POST['decision'];
$LicenseGroupID = $_POST['LicenseGroupID'];
$Quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];


$query = " CASE WHEN $decision = 'add'
       THEN
      UPDATE dbo.[tbl_license_group]
      SET Quantity = Quantity + '$Quantity'
      WHERE License_Group_ID = '$LicenseGroupID'

      ELSE WHEN $decision = 'subtract'
      THEN
      UPDATE dbo.[tbl_license_group]
      SET Quantity = Quantity - '$Quantity'
      WHERE License_Group_ID = '$LicenseGroupID'" ;

      $params1 = array($decision,$LicenseGroupID,$Quantity);                       
      $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query,$params1);

      sqlsrv_close($conn);
  ?>
   </html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? php and html seems fine, you have a number of possible issues you might want to isolate where it is failing. ie server connection, sql update ect so maybe a few more error logging would help you?

Comment: the form processes but doesn't affect the database. Notable difference I have spotted between this and others like this that work is when the form redirects to the php file , the parameters are displayed in the url ?

Answer (score 0):

Your update statement should look something like....

```
UPDATE dbo.[tbl_license_group]
SET Quantity = CASE 
                    WHEN $decision = 'add'      THEN  Quantity + '$Quantity'
                    WHEN $decision = 'subtract' THEN  Quantity - '$Quantity'
               END
WHERE License_Group_ID = '$LicenseGroupID'
```

You need to put your case statement inside your update statement not update statement inside your case statement.